# Is socket error handling different in python 2.5 than 2.7?

Tags: python, error-handling

Below is a code snip with error trace of a python scripted windows service I am running. It seems to work fine in python 2.7 on windows xp but the production machine I am using runs python 2.5 on windows server 2003. The main error I am having is `'error' object has no attribute 'errno'` Am I doing something that is fundamentally wrong for python 2.5 that works for 2.7?

**Code Snip:**

```
try:
     if s == None:
          s = self.connect()
     char = s.recv(1)
     line += char

except socket.timeout:
    if s != None:
        s.close()
    s = None
    continue

except socket.error, socket_error:
    servicemanager.LogErrorMsg(traceback.format_exc())

    if socket_error.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        if s != None:
            s.close()
        time.sleep(60)

        s =None                    
        continue

    else:
        if s != None:
            s.close()
        os._exit(-1)

else:
    pass
```

**Error Trace Snip:**

```
if socket_error.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
AttributeError: 'error' object has no attribute 'errno' 
%2: %3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [explained here](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.error), in python 2.6 :

> Changed in version 2.6: socket.error is now a child class of IOError.

and the children classes of IOError have a `errno` member.

If you want to get the errno related to your error in python < 2.6, (and assuming that the way [described here](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError) is valid for raising socket.error) you'll have to get it from the `args` attribute of your exception :

```
except socket.error, socket_error:
    if socket_error.args[0] == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
```

Comment: fair enough, but how do I properly catch connection refused

Comment: @Richard : see the second part of my (edited) answer for the connection refused handling